# Twitter Keyword Search

Tags: c#-4.0, webforms, oauthtwitterwrapper

Is it possible to do a keyword search for all users when using oAuthTwitterWrapper and c# Web Forms?

I can't find any info on how to do this, or at least none that makes sense to me.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to create a search box that will search users on Twitter?

Comment: @user2465083 Almost. I want to use a fixed string and have oAuthTwitterWrapper get results for this string. Even better would be if the results were pulled from all public Tweets on Twitter not just from the specified screenname.